# Rotating a 2D vector by small angle - clockwise and counterclockwise

Tags: c#, wpf, vector, rotation

I need to create a rotation for 2D vector by a small angle ( about 0.01 radians). I need to do this in both directions. So that in the end I have the starting vector and two identical vectors on each side of that starting vector, tilted by small angle.

Im using C# and WPF (writeablebitmap).

After learning math on the topic, If i understand correctly this following piece of code should rotate the vector:

```
     double xRotated = vector.X * Math.Cos(radians) - vector.Y * Math.Sin(radians);
     double yRotated = vector.Y * Math.Cos(radians) + vector.X * Math.Sin(radians);
```

Complete method code that should return two points, starting point and rotated point is

```
      public static Point[] RotateVector(PointF start, PointF end, double radians)
        {
            System.Windows.Vector vector = new System.Windows.Vector();
            vector.X = end.X - start.X;
            vector.Y = end.Y - start.Y;

            double xRotated = vector.X * Math.Cos(radians) - vector.Y * Math.Sin(radians);
            double yRotated = vector.Y * Math.Cos(radians) + vector.X * Math.Sin(radians);

            Point[] points = new Point[2];
            points[0].X = (int)start.X;
            points[0].Y = (int)start.Y;
            points[1].X = (int)xRotated;
            points[1].Y = (int)yRotated;

            return points;
        }
```

I call this method once with 0.01 for degrees and then -0.01.
When I shoot a ray to each corner of the screen, I would expect to see 2 additional rays on both sides, with a small tilt, on each of those main rays. When I test this the new rotated rays are way off, although it looks as if its possibly working on top left corner ray.

Im thinking that since computer screen uses X,Y coordinates starting from 0> to the right in X axis and from 0 downwards in Y axis that it has something to do with me not getting the result but im not sure how to fix this or if it really even is the source of problem. Hence Im asking for help, what am I missing?

UPDATE :: Adding some pictures to describe my problem. I am creating a RayCaster. Every structure on map, including frames, are made of lines. So each line has a starting point and ending point. A ray is shot to every line starting point and ending point. I calculate if something intersecs and if so ray ends at intersection.
IF a ray hit its destination, a line end point, two additional rays are shot with small tilted angels to go behind the corner in order to create visibility polygon. This is where I have trouble.
Im posting following 3 pictures that show my current method and what happens

[image: Empty canvas, rays are shot to each corners]

Since rays hit theyre final destinations, they two additional rays are shot. Now ideally those two additional rays are tilted on each side of the main ray, so that they can go around corner. But you can see in picture, ive dragged circles around them, those additional rays, which coordinates come from the method above, are way way off. they are nowhere near a small tilt, furthermove they are together on one side of main ray.

[image: Showing non empty map]
On second picture you see, ive dragged circles around corners, where there should be additional rays coming around the corner. but there is none

[image: Caveman fix, but rotating vector is not working yet]

Ive made a bit of a caveman alternate fix, that I set manually the destination points of those additional rays. I tell them that one ray has endpoint going +50 in x and y compared to main ray , and the other one -50. This sort of works, it creates some bugs in polygon.

Still need to fix my rotating vector!

---

UPDATE! I managed to get rotation working, I used the following code to rotate a point. THen draw a line to that rotated point. It looks similar to my original code but has a couple of extra lines that I'm not yet sure how they affect but it makes it work. THe method rotates point clockwise, I call it with angles x and 360-x to get tilts for both sides.
p1 is the point to be roatated,
p2 is the point around which rotation occurs

```
  public static Point[] RotateVectorTEST(PointF p1, PointF p2, double angle)
    {
        double radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;

        double sin = Math.Sin(radians);
        double cos = Math.Cos(radians);

        // Translate point back to origin
        p1.X -= p2.X;
        p1.Y -= p2.Y;

        // Rotate point
        double xnew = p1.X * cos - p1.Y * sin;
        double ynew = p1.X * sin + p1.Y * cos;

        // Translate point back
        Point[] test = new Point[2];
        Point newPoint = new Point((int)Math.Round(xnew + p2.X), (int)Math.Round(ynew + p2.Y));
        test[0].X = (int)Math.Round(p2.X);
        test[0].Y = (int)Math.Round(p2.Y);
        test[1] = newPoint;


        return test;

    }
```

Comment: Your miscalculation comes from the type conversion. One does not simply cast a double to an int hoping for an integer. If you need integers, create your output as `points[0].X = (int)Math.Round(start.X);` and so on. And why don't you keep your results in _double_ domain? It's much more accurate. Even though you are plotting it on pixelated screen, anti-aliasing helps you there.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have little experience so my next question is that I have writeablebitmap, lets name it bmp.
When i write bmp.DrawLineAA() all parameters required are integers. How could I pass calculated doubles as parameter to this?
Meanwhile I will try Math.Round and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @mike Also, ive updated my question to illustrate my problem. As you can see from picture 1 that current method produces quite way off  rays.

Comment: Still, round instead of truncate. I'd say your rays are there but they may be so close to the original ray that you don't see them. Try drawing the rays in different colour. The other idea is that once you rotate your vector you need to extrapolate the endpoint so it touches the image border, if I understand your logic correctly.

Comment: @Mike I managed to get it working properly. I searched for rotating a point instead of vector and got some code snippets to try. I posted the code at the bottom of my original post. It looks very similar to my original code but has a couple extra lines that im not sure what they do yet but they make it work. If you could point out what is different about these methods id appreciate it. But either way thank you for replys, and bottom line it works now :)